May I suggest questioners and answerers add correct pinyin to every multi-pronunciation character?
In Chinese, there are some characters having two or more pronunciations. This is more common than in English. I think it's good to note the pinyin so others can read the character correctly and it's also good for the learners to enlarge his vocabulary. How do you think about it?
By "multi-pronunciation character", I mean the characters have multiple pronunciations and different pronunciation corresponds to different meanings. For example,

为 wéi : as, to do, to be
为 wèi : for,to

Thus I think it's good to note the correct pinyin as in the question "What does 民以食为天 mean?", to be "What does 民以食为(wéi)天 mean?"

I'm not convinced this is absolutely necessary. I think if people see value in this they will add pinyin, but we don't need to force people to add it. 
The better answers will be up-voted, and then people can decide for themselves to add pinyin to make a better question or answer.

The problem with this is that the person asking the question may not even be aware that the character can be pronounced in different ways (whether the differences lie in tones, as in your example, or in completely different pronunciations, e.g 柏: bó, bǎi, bò). 
Therefore I think this shouldn't be an official policy and that it should instead be left to the discretion of the community's users. Posters can include such information if they are aware of it and deem it necessary and other users can make edits if they feel these will add value to the post. This, to me, seems the best solution. 

Yes... for example, we all know that 日 (rì) and 能 (néng) are not ambiguous, they are the only characters with these pronunciations.
But I think the best "easy-to-remember" policy would be: add the pronunciation to the characters that are not the most most basic ones. I'm not sure all know 飞 for example... Let's see what others have to say though. :)

Perhaps I didn't describe my suggestion clearly. I just edited it, please review.

If we include that pinyin feature we suggested, this will be already be included, no?
